# How to call the same file to my HTML twice

Tags: php

I am using this to place some repeated code onto my page from an external file:

```
<?php include_once("accordion_small.php"); ?>
```

I use this information twice on my page, but it is only showing the content at the first instance of this code.

How can I use this file twice in the same page?

Comment: Maybe because `include_once`, as the name suggests, is designed to include the file only **once**? Just change it to `include` and make sure you invoke it twice (no more, no less, but twice).

Comment: -1: This is some sort of sick joke.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP. I thought including it once meant once in that spot where I call the code. Excuse for asking a question.

Comment: @MichaelRader: There is no excuse for not having been bothered to spend 30 seconds looking it up in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `include` instead of `include_once`. `include_once` will, well, only include the script once.  The second time you call it it will be ignored.

Of course it goes to beg what is the content of that file? Is it code that just runs?  You might consider making it a function and calling it twice but including it once.

This will allow better code reuse and speed up the processing time for this page. Plus if you need to use it more than twice, hey, just call it again without including it a third or fourth or etc time.

Comment: How can I write this function? Not too familiar with PHP. It is just simple code that reduces clutter on my pages.

Comment: `function includeN($i, $include) { for($a =0; $a <= $i; $i++) { include($include); } }

Comment: @MichealRader what is the contents of your file?

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

> The include_once() statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include() statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

(so, your answer is to not use `include_once`, but just `include`)

Answer (score 0):

Necessary details given by other answers. But I think you confuse with this. You just have to put this code anywhere you want. Once, twice ... anytime...

```
<?php include "accordion_small.php"; ?>
```